# Inputting file location with spaces as arguments for an executable

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, processstartinfo

I need to input the file location from OpenFileDialog, as an argument to a .exe file, the problem is the file name has spaces and when they are called by the exe file as arguments, it breaks up on the spaces. For example if I where to get "C:\Users\Target  Files\singlefile.txt", the string would be split between "Target" and "File"

```cs
private static void CreateBinFromHex(String pathToHexFile)
{
    // Use ProcessStartInfo class
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\hex2bin.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = pathToHexFile;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch(SystemException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried different combinations in the terminal and found that enclosing the argument in a single quotes allows for a string including spaces to be used, but I cannot find a way to apply that in my program. For example---> the.exe 'C:\Users\Target  Files\singlefile.txt' works perfectly.

Comment: `$"'{pathToHexFile}'"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the behavior you want with adding an extra double quotations (`"`) for the string parameter (and escaping them):

```
pathToHexFile = "\"C:\\Users\\Target Files\\singlefile.txt\""
```

Or in your case when `pathToHexFile`  is a parameter for the method:

```
pathToHexFile = "\"" + pathToHexFile + "\"";
```

This way the the process start will call your exe like this:

```
the.exe "C:\Users\Target Files\singlefile.txt"
```

And the double quotations will threat the string as a whole.
As a comparison the single quotation (`'`) will indeed split the string into two parameters.

Tested on .NET Framework 4.7.2